# UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet does not work

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

For some reason this does not seem to work on my iPad. I have browsed a few suggestions which says that it is successful, but I can't even get this to work. Can someone please explain to me?

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {

UIAlertController *alertController;
UIAlertAction *destroyAction;
UIAlertAction *otherAction;

alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Reason"
                                      message:@"Select the following"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

destroyAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Remove All Data"
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                           // do destructive stuff here
                                       }];
otherAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Blah"
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                         // do something here
                                     }];

[alertController addAction:destroyAction];
[alertController addAction:otherAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Testing on my own, I tried changing the `preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` to `preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` and it works. Did I miss something out? Isn't the only difference between ActionSheet and Alert is their preferredStyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I were trying your code, I got an exception and crash.

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

Actually, `[alertController addAction:nil]` cause the exception. While using UIAlertController in iOS 8, you don't need to set a `NIL` button anymore. **So, remove it.**

**Edit:**

Create a IBoutlet so the popPresenter know where to pop:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

add code below in action method:

```
[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

//Create a popoverPresenter
UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController
                                                 popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.sourceView = self.button;
popPresenter.sourceRect = self.button.bounds;
```

Comment: Sry, forgot to remove that. That was actually unnecessary. However the main problem that I don't understand is why can't I use UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet as my preferredStyle?

Comment: Even after removing, my program still crashes when using UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet as my preferredStyle

Comment: @RachNg See my pullRequest also.

Comment: I see.. why do I need to add a popover?

Comment: @RachNg whereas in iPad, you need to do so with UIAlertController in iOS 8 new API.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D. Learnt something new.